# in referencing enum type why do i need to add namespace and class in declaration of the enum?

Tags: c#

```
namespace myobjects
{       
   class mylifeforms
   {     
       public enum Animal { dog, cat, mouse }       
   }    
}
```

if i want to use the the enum type in a class i need to declare the type like this:

```
myobjects.mylifeforms.Animal animal;
```

what should i do so i can declare it like:

```
Animal animal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the enum in the namspace instead of in the class. Than you can add the namepace with `using` to get what you want.

```
namespace myobjects
{       
   public enum Animal { dog, cat, mouse }       

   class mylifeforms
   {     

   }    
}
```

Now if you add

```
using myobjects;
```

in the file where you want to use your enum you will get what you want.

Comment: I'm with HCP on this, you sir are speedy!

Comment: thank you both, not that hard question and happened to be here.

Answer (score 2):

Within the `mylifeforms` class you *can* reference the `Animal` enum just by itself, but outside `mylifeforms` you need to use `mylifeforms.Animal`. It's specified in a roundabout way in sections 10.3.8.1 and 3.8 of the C# spec; the name resolution algorithm simply doesn't consider nested types when given a simple name.

You'll need to declare `Animals` in the namespace rather than the class to refer to it using it's simple name everywhere

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you have placed the enum inside of the class.

if you defined the enum inside the namespace alone, it would not be needed.

So it would look like this.

```
namespace myobjects
{       
   class mylifeforms
   {     

   }    

   public enum Animal { dog, cat, mouse }     
}
```

Then you could use `myobjects.Animal` to reference the enum.  A simple `using myobjects;` would then allow you to do it as `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a manual type alias in your `using` statements at the start of the file.

```
using Animal = MyObjects.MyLifeForms.Animal;
```

This is because you declared the `enum` within the class rather than at the namespace level. If you were to do this:

```
namespace MyObjects
{
    public class MyLifeForms
    {
        ...
    }

    public enum Animal
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It would be accessible as `Animal` to any file that uses the `MyObjects` namespace.

Comment: Also a nice solution to it, I suggested putting the enum in the namespace instead of in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you declare the enum above the class , but within the namespace ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
#define myobjects.mylifeforms.Animal Animal
```